# Unable to query restful api to retrieve json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, rest

I am attempting to query a restful API using the Jquery function `getJSON()`. The URL I am querying definitely returns a `json` object, I checked this by requesting the URL in a web browser.

This is what is displayed in the web browser when navigating to the url:
[image]

Here is the Jquery script I am using to query the URL:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("http://ip-address:7878/v2/server/status?token=B20023A49BA...", function(data){

        $(".statsContainer").innerHTML = data.name;
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* assign handler */

        alert("error occurred!");
    });

});
```

Currently I am just attempting to add the value of "name" to a HTML entity on page load. But I get an error and the alert box every time.

What am I doing wrong in retrieving this json object?

EDIT: Have added a screen capture of the content type using developer tools..
[image]

I have also attempted an ajax call to convert plain text to json without success:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url : "http://ip-address:7878/v2/server/status?token=B20023A49BA9B...",
            data : result,

            // if transaction was successful check if logic completed
            success: function(result)
            {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                alert( obj.name );

            },
            // if transaction failed show an error to the user
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert(textStatus);

            }
        });
});
```

EDIT: this is the error returned from "errorThrown".
[image]

EDIT: Why is "&callback-jQuery.." being appended onto the end of the url, is this correct?
[image]

EDIT: Here are the Headers:
[image]

Comment: What is the response content-type you are getting when loading it in browser.. is it Content-Type:application/json?

Comment: How can I find this out?

Comment: Check the web developer tool, F12 -> network -> XHR

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: sounds like a cross domain CORS issue. Need to check the proper CORS headers are available, or see if API serves jsonp. also understand `same origin policy`. Won't have any problem researching any of these terms and issues like this come up daily here

Comment: This is the API docs: https://tshock.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TSHOCKPLUGINS/REST+API+Endpoints#RESTAPIEndpoints-Description

Comment: I added the error thrown from handler.

Comment: handler error is not nearly as informative as inspecting the actual request itself. The `ContentType` question above was completely irrelevant. The response headers are the critical part to see if you can even make this request cross domain as a json request. opeinging directly in browser and security on ajax are different things

Comment: In Ajax call can you put this dataType: "jsonp", check if it works as it looks a cross domain issue

Comment: @charlietfl How can I test this?

Comment: I don't understand how this is a cross-domain issue, both the apache server for the website making the call and the API delivering the json object are on the same server? same ip address, same domain name!? webserver is on port 8080, API is on 7878.

Comment: I added some screen captures of the Headers.

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing up jQuery and javascript methods here:

`$(".statsContainer").innerHTML = data.name;`

Change that to this:

`$(".statsContainer").html(data.name);`